# Xamarin C# - How to open image loaded on webview on click?

Tags: c#, xamarin

i have a webview.
This webview loads some content, and sometimes it loads some images. 
When i click on the image on Xamarin app, nothing happens.

Is there a way to show a pop-up with the image or at least enable zoom only for images?
[i want to click the image and zoom it or click the image and show a pop-up with the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgpBH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose from one of the myriad [jQuery lightbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063199/jquery-how-can-i-show-an-image-popup-onclick-of-the-thumbnail) library, create a userscript to turn the images click action into lightbox, then [inject the userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403799/can-i-inject-javascript-and-css-into-xamarin-form-webview). This will be harder if the sites you're loading obfuscate the image logic to prevent saving.